# Rails Tests - Check alert presence throw "Undefined method `driver'"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm writing tests and I have to check the presence of an alert popup on my page after clicking on a button. I found this line that should do the trick but it throws me an error.

```
if session.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
  return true
end
```

throws

> undefined method `driver' for {}:ActionController::TestSession

I'm using RSpec with Capybara and Selenium driver for Javascript tests.

Here is the full test :

```
  def alert_present?
    if session.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
      return true
    end
    return false
  end

  it 'should display an alert to confirm the deletion', :driver => :selenium do
    click_on 'delete_submit'
    expect(alert_present?).to eq true
  end
```

Comment: is `driver` ever instantiated? if so, where?

Comment: Urg I dunno why `session` replaces `page` in my code... Gotta see the 2 solutions and picked the wrong one. It works with `page.driver...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace `session.driver.browser.switch_to.alert` with `page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert`

Comment: this will return the same error since there is no method for `driver`

Comment: Replace it with the same thing? @Aeradriel